# Why is there a difference between the node_modules folder of a project installed locally vs globally?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

Let's say I have a project with a dependency, `A`.

`A` has its own dependency on `B`.

If I `npm install A` into my project, my `node_modules` folder looks like the following. Note that `B` has been installed as a top level module:

```
/myproject
    /node_modules
        /A
        /B
```

Then if I were to depend on `myproject` from `anotherproject`, my `node_modules` folder looks like this:

```
/anotherproject
    /node_modules
        /myproject
        /A
        /B
```

But, if I were to install `myproject` as a global module `npm install -g myproject`, the `node_modules` folder ends up looking like this (no top-level `B`):

```
/myproject
    /node_modules
        /A
```

Why is this?

(npm 6.14.4}

Comment: The tree doesn't represent the deps you've described. Please post both `package-lock.json` files so we can see the difference. [Reference about the tree not being correct](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-locks)

Comment: @RandyCasburn to illustrate, create an empty project and run `npm install @babel/core`. Your `package.json` will have the single dependency, but the `node_modules` folder will be filled with top-level dependencies. Now take that same project, and install it globally. The `node_modules` folder will just have the one dependency.

Comment: Hey @Dude - What gets placed into those folders depends upon either `package-lock.json` or `npm-shrinkwraps.json`. Good luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when you install `lib A` into your project, `A` will be saved in your project `package.json` as an dependency and inside `A´s` owns `package.json` there is `B` as an dependency, which will be installed as well but will not be saved into your `package.json`. When you import your project locally to another project, all modules will have their dependencies check, so because `B` is into `A` dependencies, `B` will be added too. But, when you run a command to install globally, only `package.json` is going to be verified (not checking the dependencies of your dependencies), then `B` is not added.